# Styling select tag

Tags: css

i wanted to know if i can change the background color of the of hovering option using css only. I am not bothered about browser compatibility. But give me a solution that works across most browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Rather abrupt question, what have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the background color of the selected options in a select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089442/changing-the-background-color-of-the-selected-options-in-a-select-box)

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution first is to know that you DON'T have to expect that you page look the same in all browser. A good clean solution is use the power of each browser to do this. for example build a css for chrome/safari, another for IE and a last one for Firefox, you can do it as the follow example:

and I think use JAVASCRIPT for this purpose is NOT the best solution.

for web-kit safari/chrome

```
select{
      -webkit-appearance: button;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
      -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      background-image: url(../img/forms/arrow_blue.png), 
      -webkit-linear-gradient(#E1E1E1, #FFF 30%, #FFF);
      background-position: center right;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      color: #999;
      font-size: 90%;
      font-family:Comfortaa, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-top: 2px;
      padding-bottom: 2px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      height:40px; 
    }
```

For firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select{
        border-radius: 5px;     
        background-image: url(../img/forms/arrow_blue.png), 
        background-position: center right;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        color: #999;
        font-size: 90%;
        font-family:Comfortaa, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        height:auto; 
        padding:10px;
    }
}
```

And you can target each IE in each version as example

```
<!-- cause not every body is pretty -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="frontend/css/ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

select{ border:1px solid #EEE;
    width:auto !important;
    height:35px !important;
    padding:5px !important;
    margin:5px !important;
    line-height:1 !important;
}
```

I thinks in this way you will have nice dropdowns in all browser, while only safari/Chrome will be look exactly as you like, the other ones will behave as the user expect and you will not have to use javascript

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... you can use the :hover pseudo class to change the background-color of a select element but I just tried:

```
option:hover {
   background-color: #F00;
}
```

with no result. However:

```
select:hover option {
   background-color: #F00;
}
```

will change the background color of options when you hover of the select menu but as far as I can tell using option:hover itself won't work

Comment: not working it's giving color for all the options not the currently hovering/highlighted one

Comment: @Sankar you have only but one bit of Alex's code in? It's an either/or answer ;) the second solution in Alex's code works fine .. in FF anyway

Answer (score 2):

The select tag depends on the OS you're on,
and you can't style it the way you want
the best solution is to use jquery to replace the select with a styled list (editable with css)

take a look:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Answer (score 0):

is this the sort of thing your after?

`select:hover { background-color: red; }`

Comment: not working it's giving color for all the options not the currently hovering/highlighted one

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since I had tryed to implement this in the past and although I came to the conclusion that is not worth it most of the time, I realize sometimes it really affects the design idea (i'm not a designer but they get very frustrated about details like that), I thought I would share a resource I found that actually suggests ways to work around the fact that **it is very difficult (if not impossible) to get a consistent enough  look and feel by just applying css to the tag**. Hope it helps somebody.

[The html select tag styling challenge](http://www.slideshare.net/jdmedina17/the-html-ltselect-tag)