# Changing selected background color of a select element

Tags: html, select

I have this:

```
<div id="root">
    <select onchange="go()">
        <option value="1" selected>A
        </option><option value="2">B
        </option><option value="3">C
        </option><option value="4">D
        </option><option value="5">E
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

How can I change the standard selected background blue color to red???

I can not find any solution, not even the ones in other questions in the stackoverflow...

Comment: Are you using any Javascript Framework (jQuery, Mootools, ...) ?

Comment: I want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089442/changing-the-background-color-of-the-selected-options-in-a-select-box

Answer (score 0):

this piece of css will change the element with the attribute `selected` to red

```
option[selected]{
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

I'm not a hundred percent sure on the browser support for this selector...

Comment: That only changes the background to the selected item. I want to change the background to all the items when I click on the options..

Comment: it's not possible because it's always getting system color like change the system theme. this will get the selected color based on the current theme of os

Comment: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly on a select element. You should use an external library that will convert your select to a `div` template allowing you to change styles.

I'm using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and it works well.

Comment: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/